# Python: How to properly configure logging for a library with dictConfig?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a project folder with this structure:

```
.
├── myapp.py
└── mypackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymodule.py
```

Now I wanted to configure logging for `mypackage` as described in the documentation ([Configuring Logging for a Library](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library)) so I added a `NullHandler` to the top-level logger in my `__init__.py`:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

In `mymodule.py` I then generate an instance of the logger and use it:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

def myfunc():
    logger.warning('logging from mymodule.py')
```

In `myapp.py` I configure the logger like so:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import mypackage.mymodule as mm

if __name__ == '__main__':

    LOGGING = {'version': 1}
    console_handler = {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'}
    LOGGING['handlers'] = {'console_handler': console_handler}
    root_logger = {'handlers': ['console_handler']}
    LOGGING['loggers'] = {'': root_logger}
    
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    
    applogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    applogger.warning('logging from myapp.py')
    
    mm.myfunc()
```

Since I am adding handlers to the root-logger (`''`) I now expected to see both messages (the one in `myapp.py` and the one in `myfunc`) but I only see:

```
$ python -m myapp
logging from myapp.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed that the [`logging.config.dictConfig()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) **disables existing loggers**, unless you tell it not to. See the [*Dict Schema Details* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details):

> `disable_existing_loggers` - whether any existing non-root loggers are to be disabled. This setting mirrors the parameter of the same name in `fileConfig()`. **If absent, this parameter defaults to `True`**. This value is ignored if incremental is `True`.

(bold emphasis mine).

Your library loggers were disabled:

```
(Pdb) logging.getLogger("mypackage.mymodule").disabled
False
(Pdb) n
> /.../myapp.py(16)<module>()
-> applogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
(Pdb) logging.getLogger("mypackage.mymodule").disabled
True
```

Either explicitly set it to `False`, or set `incremental` to `True`, e.g.:

```
    LOGGING = {'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': False}
```